# SQL Server Credentials not allowing bulk load to access xml file on server

Tags: sql-server, credentials, bulk-load

I have an XML file on one of our servers which contains work data from one of our contractors. I need to be able to read the fields in this file via Geomedia Smart Client using SQL, so it will populate the Smart Client form with these values. The SQL script I have created does read successfully from this XML file using my SQL login in SQL Server, as my Windows login has access to the file location on the server. However, using the Smart Client login I don't have access so it won't work via Smart Client.

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\gmsrvdev\C$\inetpub\wwwroot\website\xmlfiles\3884.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

We have created another Windows login (DOMAIN\gmscdb) which has access to this location on the server, and added it as a SQL Server login with Windows authentication, created a credential to link the Smart Client user login to this, but it still doesn't work. I notice when logging into SQL Server using the Smart Client login I can't even see the credential, but that might just be a viewing permissions issue.

Shouldn't adding and linking the credential solve this issue?

Josh

Comment: Is this user a member of the **bulkadmin** fixed server role?

Comment: Yes it does. I think it is permissions to that actual location on the server.